# Why return the queue when using dequeue?

Tags: c

I am having some confusion regarding queues. When I return a pointer to the start of a queue as shown in the code below, and use

```
Q = enQ(Q)
```

the function works fine. However, I don't see why the function needs to return anything, since the pointer to queue is being updated within. Why does the following not seem to work when the function is made to return void?

```
enQ(Q)
```

Code:

```
// Adds item to queue
struct node* enQ(struct node* Q, int n){

    struct node* last = Q;
    struct node* new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = n;
    new->next = NULL;

    if (!Q){
        Q = new;
    } else {
        while (last->next){
            last = last->next;
        }
        last->next = new;
    }
    return Q;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time you call `enQ()` it's with a null pointer indicating that a new queue should be created. `enQ()` creates a new node and returns a pointer to it.

On subsequent calls you are correct that the return value isn't needed as it simply returns back the same `Q` that was passed in, but the first time the return value is indeed necessary. Without it calling `enQ(NULL, i)` won't have any way to return the new queue to the caller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I must have some fundamental misunderstanding about how pointers are changed in functions. In the `Q = new` line, is the value of `Q` not set to `new` automatically, and hence a return is unnecessary?

Comment: So basically, you are doing 2 different operations in the method: `queue` creation and updation. While updating the `queue` of course you are updating the content of what `Q*` is pointing to, so it is okay. 

But when you created a new `queue` your local pointer is only pointing to this new `queue`. How will the calling function know about it, unless you return the pointer or you make the input as `Q**`.

Comment: Ah, so the pointer to allocated memory `new` is a 'local' variable, in the same way that an `int` would be, and therefore needs to be returned to the function?

Comment: That is correct. If you have an assignment and dereference like `*Q = ...` then the caller might see the change. But a bare `Q = ...` only changes the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use pass-through Node to enter enQ, you should create a Queue struct and pass in Queue*

```
typedef struct Queue {
    struct node* head;
} Queue;

// Adds item to queue
void enQ(struct Queue* Q, int n) {
    struct node* tail;

    struct node* new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = n;
    new->next = NULL;

    if (Q->head == NULL) {
        Q->head = new;
    } else {
        tail = Q->head;
        while (tail->next) {
            tail = tail->next;
        }

        tail->next = new;
    }
}

void deQ(struct Queue* Q, int n) {
    if (Q->head == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    struct node* temp = Q->head;
    Q->head = Q->head->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: What happens when `Q` is `NULL` in `if (Q->head == NULL)`? Don't you need to check `if(Q == NULL)`?

Comment: @Sisir No need, if you do this, there are too many things to do.